# Iterate over dataframes with for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Due to performance I had to split up my data in several dataframes. Each frame has 300 columns and 800.000 rows.

The dataframes are named df0, df1 ... df29.

I have created them like this:

```
for j in range (0,30):
    globals()['df' + str(j)] = pd.read_parquet('C:\\Users\\helle\\Documents\\Jenny_Analytics\\train.parquet', columns=chunks[j])
```

Now I want to check data quality for all data frames and I want to do something like this:

```
df_describeAll = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Dataframe","Count"])
df_describeAll.head()

for j in range (0,29):
   cnt=df{j}.count()

    for i in range (0,cnt.size):
         if cnt[i] <800000:
              df_describeAll["Dataframe"]='df' + str(j)
              df_describeAll["Count"]=df.count()
```

My current problem is  `cnt=df{j}.count()`, I also tried `['df' + str(j)].count()`, but it never recognizes the variable as a dataframe. If I try `df0.count()` or `df10.count()` it returns a series as expected.

So what I want to do is iterate over all dataframes and put them in my `df_describeAll` whenever a column has a count below 800.000.

I think I am misusing the global variable and I really would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance

Comment: If your dataset is too large to comfortably fit in a single pandas dataframe, you might look to [dask](https://dask.org/) instead

Comment: Are you trying to create variable names using a `for loop`? Why not use a dictionary instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just load them into a list, then access them by index:

```py
dfs = [pd.read_parquet('C:\\Users\\helle\\Documents\\Jenny_Analytics\\train.parquet', columns=chunks[j]) for j in range (0,30)]

for j in range(0,29):
    cnt = dfs[j].count()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly the help I needed! Works great now :)